# Error connecting weblogic wlst from java jdeveloper

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper, wlst

I am trying to embed a WLST script in java using the WLST Interpreter. However i encounter the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: error in finding 
weblogic.Home at weblogic.Home.getInstance(Home.java:91) at 
weblogic.Home.getPath(Home.java:97) at weblogic.Home.getFile(Home.java:102) at 
weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.(WLSTInterpreter.java:116) at 
weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.(WLSTInterpreter.java:76) at 
weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.ensureInterpreter(WLSTUtil.java:157) at 
client.WLSTWrapper.doSomething(WLSTWrapper.java:19) at 
client.WLSTWrapper.main(WLSTWrapper.java:13)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure weblogic.jar is in your classpath. If it is and you still have the problem, try adding a java option like the following to your startup script:

```
-Dweblogic.home=/opt/oracle/mw/wlserver_10.3
```

Comment: Thanks i tried adding weblogic.jar to the classpath, and editing the script. Still encountered the same problem. However i found a better method to run the script using : Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("location of wlst.cmd location of your script")  Thanks for the help.